UN offices for South Asia
Most UN offices' regional headquarters for South Asia are in New Delhi, India.
Almost all employees who work there are Indian citizens or at least born-Indians.
So, as an adversary to India, how UN offices keep their employees free from Indian influence should be a big question for Pakistan.
How does Pakistan cope with this issue?

I think there's also some misunderstanding here on the scope of those offices. A quick search finds that, e.g. for UNESCO:

The South Asia Regional Office in New Delhi is mandated to cover six countries of South Asia -- Bangladesh, Bhutan, India, the Maldives, Nepal and Sri Lanka.

It doesn't cover Pakistan or Afghanistan, perhaps for political reasons.
Similarly, while WHO's office of a similar name has broader mandated coverage:

The WHO South-East Asia Region has 11 Member States - Bangladesh, Bhutan, Democratic People's Republic of Korea, India, Indonesia, Maldives, Myanmar, Nepal, Sri Lanka, Thailand, Timor-Leste. WHO has country offices in all 11 Member States. The WHO South-East Asia Regional office in based in New Delhi India.

It also doesn't seem that that office covers Pakistan (or Afghanistan). Interestingly though Indonesia didn't seem to object [to being covered by the same WHO office as India], although Indonesia is also Muslim-majority country.

For OHCHR for instance:

Pakistan is covered by OHCHR Headquarters. It also falls under the UN Human Rights Training and Documentation Centre for South-West Asia and the Arab Region established by General Assembly Resolution 60/153 of 2006.

Except the latter is not based in India, but in Qatar and note that it doesn't cover India.

The mandate of the Centre covers 25 countries, the majority of which are situated in the Arab region and three are situated in South-West Asia. The countries are: Afghanistan, Algeria, Bahrain, Comoros, Djibouti, Egypt, Iran (Islamic Republic of), Iraq, Jordan, Kuwait, Lebanon, Libya, Mauritania, Morocco, Occupied Palestinian Territory, Oman, Pakistan, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Somalia, Sudan, Syrian Arab Republic, Tunisia, United Arab Emirates and Yemen.


The UN is not a world government, it is a diplomatic forum where sovereign member states meet and discuss their differences. (The UNSC is a bit of an anomaly in this, reflecting the winners of World War II.)
The bureaucracy in the UN headquarters and the regional offices executes policy set by the member states, and to write reports which inform those policy decisions. That is influence when states without their own regional expertise cast their votes in the General Assembly. What a state does when it dislikes the bureaucratic consensus is to try and gain votes in the general assembly. Pakistani ambassadors can speak there if they want.
